# What went wrong in this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U \subset V$ and $P_{U}v$ to be an orthogonal projection of $V$ onto $U$. Show $\| P_Uv\| \leq \|v \|$

This geometrically makes sense.

Here is what I wrote.

Let $(e_1, \dots,e_m, e_{m+1}, \dots, e_n)$ be an **orthonormal** basis for $V$. Then for any $v \in V$, we have $$v = \langle v,e_1 \rangle e_1 + \dots+ \langle v,e_n \rangle e_n$$

and

$$\| v \|^2 = \| \langle v,e_1 \rangle \|^2 + \dots + \| \langle v,e_n \rangle \|^2$$

Also, $P_U(v) = \langle v,e_1 \rangle e_1 + \dots + \langle v,e_m \rangle e_m$ where we let
$(e_1, \dots,e_m)$ be an **orthonormal** basis for $U$ and $(e_{m+1}, \dots, e_n)$ be **orthonormal** base for $U^\perp$.

Then we have

$$\| v \|^2 = \| \langle v,e_1 \rangle \|^2 + \dots + \| \langle v,e_m \rangle \|^2 +  \underbrace{\| \langle v,e_{m+1} \rangle \|^2 + \dots + \| \langle v,e_n \rangle \|^2}_{\delta^2} = \| P_U v \|^2 + \delta^2$$

Rearrange a bit $\| P_U v \|^2 = \| v \|^2 - \delta^2  \leq \| v \|^2$, which gives the desired result

Comment: So what makes you think something went wrong in this proof?

Comment: The square root part. I was thinking of what happens if I had taken the negative root, but that seemed irrevelant now.

Comment: I don't see a "square root part". Where did you take any root?

Comment: @GerryMyerson To get the desired result, you still need to take the square root of both sides at the end; maybe that is what sidht is referring to?  But the norms are nonnegative so all is well.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I didn't...there appears to be a gap in what is in my mind and what I wrote...

Answer (score 3):

There's, I think, a wrong understanding of things here and this may be a rather serious mistake:

You begin by choosing an orthonormal basis $\,\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n\;$ of the whole space $\,V\,$ and then you imply that *from this very same basis* you can choose a(n orthonormal) basis $\;\{e_i\}_{i=1}^m\;$ for $\;U\;$ and also for its complement. This is false and if you give it a little thought you can find an easy counterexample with $\,\Bbb R^2\;$ and the usual, canonical basis (and the euclidean inner product, of course.)

You could, and imo *should*, have gone the other way: first choose a basis for $\,U\;$, orthonormalize it by Gram-Schmidt, complete it to a basis of the whole $\,V\;$ and again use GS to orthonormalize and etc.

Comment: I think we can avoid using the first GS since it doesn't change the span of a set of vectors. This doesn't change things too much since after doing the first GS when you do the second one there won't be a change in the vectors you applied the GS to the first time (anyway its a good answer +1)

Comment: Agreed. I mentioned GS since the OP talks about ort. basis, that's all.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work for $\mathbb{R}^2$? Let $(1,0)$ be a base for $U$ and $(0,1)$ be a base for $U^\perp$

Comment: That's not what you did, @sidht: you took the orth. basis $\;\{(1,0)\;,\;(0,1)\}\;$ and then you said that from this basis you can take (an orth) basis for $\;U\;$ . If, for example, $\,U:=\{(x,x)\in\Bbb R^2\}\;$, then you can see that no set of the first basis above is even contained in $\,U\,$, leave alone generates it.

Comment: No, I meant to say for the base $((1,0), (0,1) ) = (e_1, e_2)$. I can let $(e_1)$ be a basis for $U$ and $(e_2)$ be a basis for $U^\perp$

Comment: In your question $\,U\;$ and thus also $\,U^\perp\;$ are given, **general** , subspaces: you do *not* get to choose them!

Answer (score 3):

The thing wrong with your proof is that you don't introduce the basis in the correct way. The first time you mention it, it is just any orthonormal basis; you cannot in the sequel suddenly suppose it has any particular relation to the subspaces $U$ and $U^\perp$. But if with a bit of foresight, you start choosing an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ of the subspace $U$ (where $m=\dim U$) and another orthonormal basis $\{e_{m+1},\ldots,e_n\}$ of the subspace $U^\perp$, then you will have no difficulty in proving that $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of$~V$ (but not just *any* orthonormal basis), and using that basis your proof runs fine.

By the way, you don't really need to use any basis at all for this result. By the definition of orthogonal projection one has $P_U(v)\perp v-P_U(v)$, so that by Pythagoras' theorem $\|v\|^2=\|P_U(v)\|^2+\|v-P_U(v)\|^2$ whence $\|v\|\geq\|P_U(v)\|$.